# How can i ask a user to select a setting on startup for the first time?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

how can i setup shared preferences to show an alert box if their is no default setting.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* RR - Restore Prefrences */
         SharedPreferences settings =
         this.getSharedPreferences("com.sample.test",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         Boolean isBackgroundWhite = settings.getBoolean("BgColor", true);
             //triggerAlert();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SharedPreferences.contains()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains%28java.lang.String%29) to test is a preference has ever been set. If not, show your dialog.

```
if(!settings.contains("BgColor")){

    // Make a call to your dialog code here.  
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I added a source to your answer. Good answer, though. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharedPreferences.contains](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains%28java.lang.String%29) for checking is SharedPreference contain key or not when user start application first time as:

```
     SharedPreferences settings =
     this.getSharedPreferences("com.sample.test",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

     if (settings.contains("BgColor")) {
        // means key is present in preference 
        //so no need to show settings
      }else{
         // key not present in preference so 
         // store key in preference and show setting
      }
```

Comment: i managed to get a variation of this working but where on the device are these settings stored. can i erase the file manually from eclipse so i can keep debugging?

Comment: @blu : SharedPreference store in application memory so for debugging you can clear all application data from `Settings->App->Your Application - > Clear Data`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.getSharedPreferences("com.sample.test",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean
    ("firstLaunch", true)){ //Display your dialog settings
    this.getSharedPreferences("com.sample.test",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit.
        setBoolean ("firstLaunch", false).commit;
}
```